# Find max sum of SubMatrix 3x3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I practice work with matrix but I stuck here. I need to find max sum of subMatrix.

```
const matrix = [ 
    [ 1,  1,  3,  3,  5],
    [-6, -7,  2, -3, -1],
    [ 3,  0, -4,  5,  9],
    [ 7, -7,  0,  1,  0],
    [-7, -6, -4, -4,  9],
]
```

The current matrix is 5x5. I need to find the maxSum of 3x3 sub matrixes. So the maxSum here is 19. I highlight here the submatrix having this sum:

```
            +----------+
     1   1  |  3  3  5 | 
    -6  -7  |  2 -3 -1 | 
     3   0  | -4  5  9 | 
            +----------+
     7  -7     0  1  0
    -7  -6    -4 -4  9
```

The script should be working with bigger matrix. I need help I can't make it iterate properly over each 3x3 matrix.

```
const subLength = 3 * 3;
let maxSum = 0;
for (let subMatrix = 0; subMatrix < subLength; subMatrix++) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++) {
        for (let cols = subMatrix; cols < matrix.length; cols++) {
            sum += matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }
    if (maxSum < sum) {
        maxSum = sum;
    }
}
console.log(maxSum);
```

The code works fine with that matrix but not with another and I know the problem is in the third nested loop and probably, something in the first. In the third I have to iterate from 0 to 3 next from 1 to (3 + 1), from (3 + 2) and moving on next array on the second row and start from zero again.

Can you fix my code ?

Comment: Why does your matrix have 7 values in its last row?

Comment: thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier if you replace your outer loop with two outer loops: one for what the first row will be of the submatrix, and another for its first column. Then the two inner loops should iterate over the 3 rows and 3 columns of the submatrix that starts there.

Here is your code with minimal changes:

```js
function maxSubSum(matrix, subLength) {
    let maxSum = 0;

    for (let firstRow = 0; firstRow <= matrix.length - subLength; firstRow++) {
        for (let firstCol = 0; firstCol <= matrix[0].length - subLength; firstCol++) {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for (let col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    sum += matrix[firstRow+row][firstCol+col];
                }
            }
            if (maxSum < sum) {
                maxSum = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}

const matrix = [ 
    [ 1,  1,  3,  3,  5],
    [-6, -7,  2, -3, -1],
    [ 3,  0, -4,  5,  9],
    [ 7, -7,  0,  1,  0],
    [-7, -6, -4, -4,  9],
];

console.log(maxSubSum(matrix, 3));
```

There are of course more concise ways to code this, but I decided to stick with the patterns you were already trying to use.

Comment: It works with 9 of 12 cases. 3 cases gives me wrong answer and return 0. May be I missed something in the question. Can you check ? Here is my task. I have the size of matrix
https://judge.telerikacademy.com/problem/27maxsuminmatrix

Comment: I had assumed that matrix was square, but it turns out to be rectangular. See the update of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function with `reduce` method that takes col and row params and slice them from original arrays but for inner array you just reverse the element order.

```js
const matrix = [
  [1, 1, 3, 3, 5],
  [-6, -7, 2, -3, -1],
  [3, 0, -4, 5, 9],
  [7, -7, 0, 1, 0],
  [-7, -6, -4, -4, 9, 11, 40],
]

function sum(matrix, row, col) {
  return matrix.slice(0, row).reduce((r, e) => {
    [...e].reverse().slice(0, col).forEach(c => r += c)
    return r;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(sum(matrix, 3, 3))
```

Or you could slice from the end of inner array and use one more reduce.

```js
const matrix = [
  [1, 1, 3, 3, 5],
  [-6, -7, 2, -3, -1],
  [3, 0, -4, 5, 9],
  [7, -7, 0, 1, 0],
  [-7, -6, -4, -4, 9, 11, 40],
]

function sum(matrix, row, col) {
  return matrix.slice(0, row).reduce((r, e) => {
    return r + e.slice(-col).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
  }, 0)
}

console.log(sum(matrix, 3, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a part of the matrix first and then get the sum of the sub matrix.

```js
const
    matrix = [[1, 1, 3, 3, 5], [-6, -7, 2, -3, -1], [3, 0, -4, 5, 9], [7, -7, 0, 1, 0], [-7, -6, -4, -4, 9, 11, 40]],
    cols = 3,
    rows = 3,
    left = -3,
    top_ = 0,                                   // top is a reserved property of windows
    sum = matrix
        .slice(top_, top_ >= 0 ? rows : undefined)
        .map(a => a.slice(left, left >= 0 ? cols : undefined))
        .reduce((r, a) => a.reduce((s, v) => s + v, r), 0);

console.log(sum);
```